# Reusable pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, html, pagination

This is a pagination program that works perfectly fine. I want to be able to save this code and reuse it whenever I need it as a method in jQuery (read: `$(myData).pagination()`).

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var post = $(".note > li")
    var page= 1;
    var postsPerPage = 5;
    var numPages = Math.ceil(post.length/postsPerPage)

    for(j=0;j<numPages;j++){ //render menu
        $(".paginationIndex").append("<li><a href='#' class='pageNum'>"+(j+1)+"</a></li>")
    }

    $(".paginationIndex li:first-child a").addClass("active") //add active class to page_1

    $(".pageNum").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".pageNum").removeClass("active")
        $(this).addClass("active")
        page = parseInt($(this).html())
        pagination(page, postsPerPage) // execute onclick
    })

    var pagination = function(p, ppp){ //root function
        $.each(post, function(i,v){
        i < ppp*p && i>=ppp*(p-1)?$(this).show():$(this).hide();
        })
    }

    pagination(page, postsPerPage)


})
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="note">
  <li>
some content 1........
  </li>
  <li>
some content 2........
  </li>
  <li>
some content 3........
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="paginationIndex">
 <!-- children rendered with jQuery-->
</ul>
```

Comment: There is a really good tutorial at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going the whole plugin route (to which I would suggest using the jQueryUI widget design), I have made a few modifications to clean up your code:

[Commented version over at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KALpP/2/)

```
(function ($, Math) {     
    $(function () {     
        var $posts = $(".note > li"),     
            page = 1,
            pageSize = 2, //you would want to change this back to 5
            numPages = Math.ceil($posts.length/pageSize),
            j,     
            $paging = $(".paginationIndex"),     
            $lastactive,     
            s = '';

        for(j=0;j<numPages;j++) {     
            s+="<li><a href='#Page+";
            s+=(j+1);     
            s+="' class='pageNum' title='Go to page ";
            s+=(j+1);     
            s+="'>";
            s+=(j+1);
            s+="</a> </li>";     
        }
        $paging.append(s);

        $lastactive = $paging.find("li:first-child a").addClass("active");     

        $paging.on('click', 'a', function(e) {     
            e.preventDefault();
            $lastactive.removeClass("active");     
            $lastactive = $(this).addClass("active");
            page = +$lastactive.html();     
            pagination();     
        });

        var pagination = function() {
            $posts.hide().slice(pageSize*(page-1), pageSize*page).show();
        };

        pagination();
    });
}(jQuery, Math));
```

Comment: +1. Thanks so much. I like your coding style. One thing... why did you pass the `Math` object parameter to the wrapping IIFE?

Comment: As a general practice, I like to pass in all globals that I use. Here I could have passed in `Math.ceil` instead (I'm about 50/50 on that being a good idea or not). It makes it easy to see what dependencies the JavaScript has.